# Not displaying output on wildcard search

Tags: powershell

When I run the below code, I get the following result.

```
import-module activedirectory
Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -Like "*1234*"} -Property * | Format-Table Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack -Wrap -Auto

Name       OperatingSystem      OperatingSystemServicePack
----       ---------------      --------------------------
DEP12345LT                                                
CLC41234DT Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1            
A123456    Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1
```

But when I run this code

```
import-module activedirectory
$assetid = Read-Host "Assest id"
Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -Like "*$assetid*"} -Property * | Format-Table Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack -Wrap -Auto
```

I get

```
PS U:\> V:\General Helpful Scripts and Code\wild_card_pc_number_finder.ps1
Assest id: 1234

PS U:\>
```

Why isn't it displaying the results when try to pass a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `-Filter` parameter isn't evaluating the string `"*$assetid*"` properly. If you create the string in another variable first and then use it, it will work.

```
Import-Module activedirectory
$assetid = Read-Host "Assest id"
$like = "*$assetid*"
Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -Like $like} -Property * | Format-Table Name,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemServicePack -Wrap -Auto
```

Another way around this is to use create a string in `PowerShell Expression Language Syntax` for the `-Filter` parameter ([more info](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531527(v=ws.10).aspx)).

```
-Filter "Name -like '*$assetid*'"
```

From what I can under stand the reason why this isn't working is that `PowerShell` is tries to converts `{Name -Like "*$assetid*"}` into `PowerShell Expression Language Syntax` which is basically a string so you will end you will something like this after converting.

```
'Name -Like "*$assetid*"'
```

Meaning you are searching for `*$assetid*` and not the value of the variable.

This why you can use the second example I have provide. As `PowerShell` will evaluate the string before it passed it to the parameter. Whereas the method you were using will be passing a `{ .. }` script block and the cmdlet will then try and convert it to PS Expression Language syntax.

Comment: Cool! It worked! Is there a reason it can't evaluate that? and why i need to create the string prior and pass it through.

Comment: @TuckRollworthy I have updated my answer and tried to explain why this isn't working.